# Passing factory_girl object to step definition in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd, factory-bot

Learning Cucumber testing with Factory_girl and I have an admittedly n00b question:

How do I use my Factory_Girl step definitions in Cucumber?

For example, I have the following test for the User controller "Show" view:

```
  Scenario: View Profile Page
    Given a user exists
    When I am on the user show page #NOT SURE HOW TO MAKE THIS WORK
    Then I should see "Your Profile" in the selector "h2"
    And I should see "Edit Profile" in a link
    And I should see "Delete Account" in a link
```

And a 'user' Factory setup like so:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "UserNumber#{n}" }
    email { "#{:name}@fakemail.com" }
    phone 8457975800
  end
end
```

I've made sure to add the `require "factory_girl/step_definitions"`line to my env.rb file, which works fine.

The problem is that I have no idea how to go about writing a step definition for the `When I am on the user show page` portion that uses the 'user' Factory? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/10983530140/getting-sequential-a-look-into-a-factory-girl
Take a look at this factory girl antipattern. Seems even factory girl authors don't have better answer on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Got it, sorry for the n00bness

```
When /^I am on the user show page$/ do
  user = Factory.create(:user)
  visit "/users/#{user.id}"
end
```